# Let only one instance of the same function exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, recurrence

I have this onclick event listener on `li` items in a `ul`, that starts a setInterval function, the problem is if i click on a second `li` item another instance of the same intervalled function starts and the previous one keeps going.
How can i "delete" the previous one and let only the last one to "exists"?

The solutions I found for the similar questions didn't work for me.

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

  var texta = document.getElementById('myTextarea');

   var item = event.target.closest('#yourlists li');
   if (item) {
    var ite = event.target.closest('#yourlists li').innerHTML;

    setInterval(function autoSave(){
          var listText = texta.value.split('\n');
          localStorage.setItem(ite, JSON.stringify(listText));
    }, 5000);

   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). From docs,

> The clearInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin cancels a timed, repeating action which was previously established by a call to setInterval().

```
var myInterval;

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
     // ... code
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(function autoSave(){
      // ... code
    }, 5000);
    // ... code
});
```

Comment: This works! thank you, i think the similar solutions i tried didn't work because I didn't declare the var outside of the eventListener.

Comment: @m4tt - Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` returns an ID that you can use to stop it with later...

```
var intervalId = 0;

document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    var texta = document.getElementById('myTextarea');

    var item = event.target.closest('#yourlists li');

    if (item) {
        var ite = event.target.closest('#yourlists li').innerHTML;

        // clear any existing interval handler
        clearInterval(intervalId);

        // create a new one
        intervalId = setInterval(function autoSave(){
            var listText = texta.value.split('\n');
            localStorage.setItem(ite, JSON.stringify(listText));
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval` function returns an ID which you can use to stop that interval.

Here is an example:

```
var intervalID
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    ....
    clearInterval(intervalID)
    intervalID = setInterval(function autoSave(){
         ....
    }, 5000);
    ....
})
```